# Keeping punctuation in R Document Term Matrix

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I'm trying to make a `DocumentTermMatrix` in `R`, using the parameter `control = list()` to limit the terms to a pre-defined list of text-based emojis (:D, :), :(, etc.). However, dtm doesn't pick up certain emojis (like `":D"` or `":)"`), but some other works fine (`":))"`) . My code:

```
text = c(":D", ":))" ) 
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text)
corpus = tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)
dtm = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus, list(dictionary = c(":D" , ":))" )))
emojidf <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(dtm))

  :D :))
1  0   0
2  0   1
```

To fix this, I could use `content_transformer` and `gsub` to change the problematic emojis to words. However, I'd like to know how `DocumentTermMatrix` or even `Corpus` treat punctuation as words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues (see `?DocumentTermMatrix` and `?termFreq`): The wordLengths filter by default demands a minimum word length of 3 characters. And tolower by default turns `:D` into `:d`. So try:

```
library(tm)
text <- c(":D", ":))" ) 
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(
  corpus, 
  control = list(
    dictionary = c(":D" , ":))"), 
    wordLengths=c(-Inf,Inf), 
    tolower=FALSE
  )
)
as.matrix(dtm)
#     Terms
# Docs :)) :D
#    1   0  1
#    2   1  0
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch on `tolower` default! I figured out the 3 letters lower bound, but didn't think tolower would be embedded in dtm, since I usually do that with tm_map before making dtm

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I run the exact same code, it doesn't calculate frequency for me: 

  
      Terms
Docs :D :))
   1  0   0
   2  0   0

Any ideas?

Comment: @ChrisL Replace `Corpus` with `VCorpus` and read `?DocumentTermMatrix` under _"This is different for a SimpleCorpus"_ - there was a change in tm a while ago...

Comment: @lukeA Thank you. You have no idea how long I spent on this.